# Multiple condition in CASE

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, case

i want to create a query that can select multiple conditions using CASE.
I have the below query that sum when number of windows it's more than 0 but whe I combined to create a 
"Windows_multiple" doesn't work. It's multiple when have more than one type of windows.

```
Select
SUM(CASE when h.number_of_windows_b > 0 then h.hh_weight end)/15 as Windowsb_only,
SUM(case when h.number_of_windows_c > 0 then h.hh_weight end)/15 as Windowsc_only,
SUM(case when h.number_of_windows_o > 0 then h.hh_weight end)/15 as Windowso_only,
```

The code above works but when I'm trying to create a query that sum h.number of windows when are multiple I'm not getting the expected output. I'm using the below query:

```
SUM(CASE when h.number_of_windows_b > 0 AND (h.number_of_windows_c > 0 OR  h.number_of_windows_o > 0) 
         then h.hh_weight )/15
         when h.number_of_windows_c  > 0 AND (h.number_of_windows_b > 0 OR  h.number_of_windows_o > 0) 
         then h.hh_weight )/15
         when h.number_of_windows_o  > 0 AND (h.number_of_windows_b > 0 OR  h.number_of_windows_c > 0) 
         then h.hh_weight end)/15 as Windows_Multiple
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

You might just have premature `end`s:

```
SUM(CASE when h.number_of_windows_b > 0 AND (h.number_of_windows_c > 0 OR  h.number_of_windows_o > 0) 
         then h.hh_weight / 15
         when h.number_of_windows_c  > 0 AND (h.number_of_windows_b > 0 OR  h.number_of_windows_o > 0) 
         then h.hh_weight / 15
         when h.number_of_windows_o  > 0 AND (h.number_of_windows_b > 0 OR  h.number_of_windows_c > 0) 
         then h.hh_weight / 15
     END) as Windows_Multiple
```

Comment: I changed it on the original question 'cause I wrote it wrong. Thats not the solution